# (Django) Cannot assign "u'1'": "StaffProfile.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django

I have a model like below:

```
class StaffProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    maas = models.FloatField()
    maas_gunu = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

When I try to insert data with a code like below:

```
staffprofilesay = StaffProfile.objects.filter(user = user_id).count()

     if staffprofilesay > 0:
        staffprofile = StaffProfile.objects.get(user = user_id)
     else:    
        staffprofile = StaffProfile()

     staffprofile.user = user_id
     staffprofile.maas = calisan_formu.cleaned_data["maas"]
     staffprofile.maas_gunu = calisan_formu.cleaned_data["maas_gunu"]
     staffprofile.save()
```

I get an error like this:

```
Cannot assign "u'1'": "StaffProfile.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

What am I supposed to do?

PS: I'm using Django's User model

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to assign a User object e.g.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

staffprofile.user = user
```

Comment: I have a similar problem (but, not with auth_user instance).  I have an id (a long), but can't assign it to the field.  So, I'm going to have to make a round trip to the database to get an option before I can assign it?  What's the point of a foreign key on the database?  It's going to check and see if the id is valid.  Is there a work around for this?  Am I really going to have to make a round trip to fetch the option just to get the id, that I already have?

Answer (score 5):

`user` needs to be an instance of the `User` model, not a unicode object (which is what you are passing it).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to pass User instance in `staffprofile.user = user_id` user id place.

As @david-s pointed out in a comment, if you don't have a user instance, you have to fetch from DB with an additional query.

Instead you can directly do is
`staffprofile.user_id = user_id` because Django behind the scene append `_id` in table for foreign keys so `staffprofile.user` will end `staffprofile.user_id`