# Using Django and Postgres to store phone numbers

Tags: python, django, postgresql, forms, post

I currently want to make a web app in django with a form that asks a user to input a phone number and submit, and I want that number they submit to be stored in a database using postgres. I'm having a hard time finding information on how to use post requests in django to connect to postgres.

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Test Form 1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send message">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
# from main.views import first
from main import views as test_app_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('', first)
    path('', test_app_views.FormView1.as_view())
]
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from phone_field import PhoneField
from main.models import Post

class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = PhoneField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('phone',)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from phone_field import PhoneField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    phone = PhoneField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import HomeForm

class FormView1(FormView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    # form_class = RequiredInputsForm
    # success_url = '/index/success/'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()

            phone = form.cleaned_data['post']
            form = HomeForm()
            return redirect('index:index')

            args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

How can I get this to store the phone number in the postgres db after I've initialized the project to use it? This was what I tried but I am consistently getting the error: 'ValueError at /
Cannot assign ">": "Post.user" must be a "User" instance.'

I think what I'm trying to do is quite simple, I've just never done it before with django and postgres, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you don't have a "User" instance to save...I see you are setting post.user = request.user, but have you checked that request.user is actually a valid object? I don't see any logic where a user would login, so where are you setting request.user? This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616569/django-cannot-assign-u1-staffprofile-user-must-be-a-user-instance

Comment: @Jim yes you're correct thank you! I changed it and I'm getting a new error now, I posted the updated code and error here as a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333044/noreversematch-at-main-insert-num-django