# NoReverseMatch at /main/insert_num/ Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, post, web-applications

I'm trying to make to make a django web app which has a form that asks a user to input a phone number and stores that number in a postgres database. The following code is giving me the error:

> NoReverseMatch at /main/insert_num/
>
> Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

And I can't figure out what the issue is, can someone help?

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Test Form 1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="{% url 'insert_my_num' %}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- {{ form.as_p }} -->
    <input type="submit" value="Send message">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from phone_field import PhoneField
from main.models import Post

class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = PhoneField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('phone',)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from phone_field import PhoneField


class Post(models.Model):
    phone = PhoneField()
```

**main/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('insert_num/', views.insert_my_num,name='insert_my_num')
]
```

**project/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('main/',include('main.urls'))
]
```

**views.py**

```
def insert_my_num(request: HttpRequest):
    phone = Post(request.POST.get('phone'))
    phone.save()
    return redirect('')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `views.py` is a little off - you aren't rendering your form anywhere. I drafted up a quick app (which I think does what you're looking for) - let me know if this works:

*main/templates/index.html*

Here, I just set the form's action to `""` (that's all you need here) and uncommented the `form.as_p` line

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Test Form 1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send message">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*main/views.py*

Note the differences here, we are testing the request type and taking appropriate action based on what kind of request is coming in. If it's a POST request we process the form data and save to the database. If not, we need to display a blank form for the user to complete.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import HomeForm


def insert_my_num(request):
    # Check if this is a POST request
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Create an instance of HomeForm and populate with the request data
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        # Check if it is valid
        if form.is_valid():
            # Process the form data - here we're just saving to the database
            form.save()
            # Redirect back to the same view (normally you'd redirect to a success page or something)
            return redirect('insert_my_num')
    # If this isn't a POST request, create a blank form
    else:
        form = HomeForm()

    # Render the form
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Let me know if that works!

Comment: Glad I could help!