# Django cant return a class based view user id

Tags: django

My goal is to update the view using ajax. when the user enters a value in those 3 fields and save those fields to the database with for this user.
I have a user model with 3 text field as follow

```
class Q3Sign(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length =255,blank =True)
title2 = models.CharField(max_length =255, blank = True)
title3 = models.CharField(max_length =255,blank =True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE )

class Meta:
    db_table = "Q3sign"
```

and my view is as fellow, I am getting the following error when I try to populate the fields.
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: Q3sign.user_id

```
class Createcourse(generic.CreateView):
    model = Q3Sign
    fields = ['title','title2','title3']
    template_name = 'Q3canA/create_course.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('create_course')


    def create_course(self, request):
        members = Q3Sign.objects.all()
        return render (request,'Q3canA/create_course.html' , {'members':members})
    
def insert(request):
        member = Q3Sign(title=request.POST['title'], title2=request.POST['title2'], 
        title3=request.POST['title3'], user=request.POST['user.id'])
        member.save()
        return redirect('create_course')
```

and here is my html

```
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Courses</h2>
        <form method=post>
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p}}
          <input type="submit" value="Create course" />
        </form>

      </div>
      <form method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-inline">
              <label>Course 1</label>
              <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control"/>
          </div>
      <br />
      <div class="form-inline">
              <label>Course 2</label>
                 <input type="text" id="title2" name="title2" class="form-control"/>
              <label>Course 3</label>
              <input type="text" id="title3" name="title3" class="form-control"/>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
      </form>
      <hr style="border-top:1px solid #000; clear: both;" />
      <table class"table table-bordered">
        <thead class = "alert-warning">
          <tr>
            <th>Course 1</th>
            <th>Course 2</th>
            <th>Course 3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for member in members %}
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{member.user.id}}</td>
            <td>{{member.title}}</td>
            <td>{{member.title2}}</td>
            <td>{{member.title3}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor%}
        </tbody>
      </table>



      {% endblock %}
```

Update now the fields disappeared :
[image]

Here is my URLs

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.home, name='home'),
    #Auth
    path('signup', views.Signup.as_view(), name = 'signup'),
    path('login', auth_view.LoginView.as_view(), name = 'login'),
    path('logout', auth_view.LogoutView.as_view(), name = 'logout'),

    #Q3Course

    path('createcourse',views.Createcourse.as_view(), name = 'create_course'),
    url(r'^create_course', views.Createcourse.createcourse, name='create_course'),



]

urlpatterns +=  static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

thanks to @Fifon the code now working.
The only issue I need to understand is why the if statement is not working.
if the fields are empty or if it contains a test it still saves it in the database and not raising the alert in the if clause?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').on('click', function(){

        $title = $('#title').val();
        $title2 = $('#title2').val();
        $title3 = $('#title3').val();
        $user = $('#user').val();


        if($title.toLowerCase().indexOf('test') == -1 || $title2 == "" || $title3 == "" || $user = ""){
            alert("Please complete field");
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/create_course",
                data:{
                    title: $title,
                    title2: $title2,
                    title3: $title3,
                    user: $user,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                },
                success: function(){
                    alert('Save Data');
                    $('#title').val('');
                    $('#title2').val('');
                    $('#title3').val('');
                    $('#user').val('');

                    window.location = "/create_course";
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You are passing the User ID, rather than a User instance. This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616569/django-cannot-assign-u1-staffprofile-user-must-be-a-user-instance

Comment: You are also not explicitly passing any user info in the AJAX POST request. Should it be the currently logged in user? If so, you can use request.user in your insert() method

Comment: Furthermore, it may be advisable to use a ModelForm, and to make use of the in-built validation. Currently the only validation you are doing is checking that the text fields are not empty.

Comment: Hi Fifon, I tried the 2 following steps 
user2 = User.objects.get(id=user.id)
member = Q3Sign(title=request.POST['title'], title2=request.POST['title2'], title3=request.POST['title3'], user=user2)
that returned NameError: name 'user' is not defined
The second one was member = Q3Sign(title=request.POST['title'], title2=request.POST['title2'], title3=request.POST['title3'], user=request.user ) 
and it return the same first error

Comment: @Ffion did you made a post and delete ?

Comment: Yes, I noticed some necessary improvements straight away so I deleted it. I have edited it now and published it again. Please comment on that answer if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no need for your insert() method. As you have a CreateView, you should use this, which will handle creating your objects and inserting them into the database. You should make use of the form this CreateView provides for you, rather than manually creating HTML for the form. This will make your life easier and ensure proper validation takes place. Something like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates):

```
<form method="POST" id="create-course-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Create course" />
</form>
```

Your HTML is a little bit confusing right now – there is a form rendered using the {{ form.as_p }} template tag, and a manually rendered form. Take care here.

In your AJAX call, you should submit the form data, to the URL associated with your CreateView. I can't see your urls.py, but for example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{% url 'course-create' %}",
    data: $('#create-course-form').serialize(),
    ...
```

You also need to make sure the form doesn't get submitted with an ordinary POST request (you want to use AJAX), by using preventDefault():

```
$('#create-course-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Putting it all together, back in your Createcourse view, you should define the form_valid(self) method, so that you can add in the user info. As you are using AJAX, you need to return a JsonResponse. E.g.:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = request.user
        self.object.save()

        return JsonResponse({'success':True})
    else:
        return super(CreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

You also need to handle the situation in which your form is invalid as follows:

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=400)
    else:
        return super(CreateView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Finally, you will need to handle the response in your JavaScript. Success doesn't necessarily mean the form was valid and the course was created. If there are errors, you will need to display them to the user.

**Update**: You have two URLs both called 'create_view'. Remove the second one. Everything can be done from the one CreateView (Createcourse). In order to still have access to 'members', define get_context_data() as follows:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["members"] = Q3Sign.objects.all()
    return context
```

Comment: @Fifon Thank you so much for your comment.
I tried the above and this the error that I got. I guess my mind start to freeze since i have been working for too long.
"Q3Sign.user" must be a "User" instance.

Comment: Take a break and I'll check in again, happy to help. Is there definitely a user logged in? You may want to add a @login_required decorator to your view.

Comment: @Fifon The good news it is not giving me an error anymore. And it shows the previous field I created in the view. The issue is that the 3 fields that i use as a form got disappeared and the button only exists.I updated a screenshot above

Comment: That is good. Regarding the missing input fields, it sounds like the form variable isn't being passed to the template from the view. What is the name of the template you have your HTML in? This should match the one specified in your CreateView (Q3canA/create_course.html)

Comment: Could you also show your urls.py file please?

Comment: Just shared it. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Please post the urls in your original question, rather than as an edit to my response. And let me know about the template names (see above comment).

Comment: Done. sorry didnt notice that I was editing your comment.

Comment: Thanks. You have two URLs called create_course. Get rid of the second one. But to make sure you can access 'members' in the template, you will need to define request_context in the CreateView. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Fifon Thank you so much now it is working. 
there is 2 final issue I have been trying to fix since then.
1- now the table display all the courses('titles fields') in it I wanted to display only related user fields.
2- the ajax file use to trigger an alert when the fields doesnt contain a certain word( ie. name) no it doesnt.

Comment: For number 1, you need to use filter() instead of all(), e.g. Q3Sign.objects.filter(user=request.user) - this will filter the Q3Sign objects so the returned QuerySet only contains those where the user is the currently logged in user (rather than all the objects).

Comment: For number 2, you need to work on your AJAX success function in the JavaScript. As I said before, success here just means the request was successfully executed, not that the form validated and the object was successfully created.  You need to update yor success function to handle the response form fom_valid (success) or form_invalid (form.errors) appropriately.

Comment: How are you getting on @Shaa'banMego?

Comment: @Fifon Hi man sorry for my late replay. I finished 1 day after we talked about it. Thank you so  much.